# why this error showing "MessageContext cannot be resolved to a type" in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to convert my existing spring mvc application into spring boot. I managed to convert all other files but I am not able to solve this error. How can i show message using  messagecontext and messagebuilder() in spring boot?

I am using

**spring-boot-starter-parent version-2.0.6.RELEASE**

this is my code that showing error:

```
public String validateUser(User user, MessageContext error) {

    String transitionValue = "success";

    // checking if password matches confirm password

    if(!(user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword()))) {

        error.addMessage(new MessageBuilder()
                .error()
                .source("confirmPassword")
                .defaultText("Password does not match the confirm password!")
                .build()
                );
        transitionValue = "failure";
    }

    return transitionValue;
}
```

this is RegisterHandler that showing error

**RegisterHandler.java**

```
package net.kzn.onlineshopping.handler;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.binding.message.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.binding.message.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import net.kzn.onlineshopping.model.RegisterModel;
import net.kzn.shoppingbackend.dao.UserDAO;
import net.kzn.shoppingbackend.dto.Address;
import net.kzn.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart;
import net.kzn.shoppingbackend.dto.User;

@Component
public class RegisterHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public RegisterModel init() {

        return new RegisterModel();
    }

    public void addUser(RegisterModel registerModel, User user) {
         registerModel.setUser(user);
    }

    public void addBilling(RegisterModel registerModel, Address billing) {
         registerModel.setBilling(billing);;
    }

    public String saveAll(RegisterModel model) {
        String transitionValue = "success";

        //fetch the user

        User user = model.getUser();

        if(user.getRole().equals("USER")) {
            Cart cart = new Cart();
            cart.setUser(user);
            user.setCart(cart);

        }

        //encode the password
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        //save the user
        userDAO.add(user);

        //get the address

        Address billing = model.getBilling();
        billing.setUserId(user.getId());
        billing.setBilling(true);

        // save the address
        userDAO.addAddress(billing);

        return transitionValue;
    }

    public String validateUser(User user, MessageContext error) {

        String transitionValue = "success";

        // checking if password matches confirm password

        if(!(user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword()))) {

            error.addMessage(new MessageBuilder()
                    .error()
                    .source("confirmPassword")
                    .defaultText("Password does not match the confirm password!")
                    .build()
                    );
            transitionValue = "failure";
        }

        // check the uniqueness of the email id

        if(userDAO.getByEmail(user.getEmail())!=null) {

            error.addMessage(new MessageBuilder()
                    .error()
                    .source("email")
                    .defaultText("Email address is already used!")
                    .build()
                    );
            transitionValue = "failure";
        }

        return transitionValue;
    }

}
```

how can i write error message using spring boot?

Comment: You should follow this link.http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-exception-handling-for-rest-services

Comment: How are you creating an object of MessageContext. it should be created like this MessageContext messages = context.getMessageContext(); and pass to the validateUser.

Comment: can you check your messageContext object?messageContext object will be created by context object like context.getMessageContext()

Comment: Have you added [Spring-Web-Flow](https://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/) to your dependencies? `MessageContext` / `MessageBuilder` are parts of Spring-Web-Flow

Comment: Also, you don't import the classes `MessageContext` / `MessageBuilder`. Please add the necessary import statements.

Comment: do I have to manually provide Spring-Web-Flow? it is not included with spring-boot-starter-web?

Comment: problem solved after importing spring-web-flow. I Thought its automatically downloaded with spring-boot-starter-web. thanks.